# SmartFox error NullPointerException at SFSGameApi.populateInvitations

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

I need some help with SmartFox Server, please.

```
ISFSGameApi gameAPI = SmartFoxServer.getInstance().getAPIManager().getGameApi();
        List<User> invitees = new ArrayList<User>();
        invitees.add(invitee);

        CreateSFSGameSettings settings = new CreateSFSGameSettings();
        settings.setMaxUsers(2);
        settings.setMaxVariablesAllowed(5);
        settings.setGame(true);
        settings.setInvitationExpiryTime(waitingTime);
        settings.setMinPlayersToStartGame(2);
        settings.setName("rm-" + sender.getName());
        settings.setDynamic(true);
        settings.setLeaveLastJoinedRoom(false);
        settings.setAutoRemoveMode(SFSRoomRemoveMode.WHEN_EMPTY);
        settings.setInvitedPlayers(invitees);

        try {
        gameAPI.createGame(getParentExtension().getParentZone(), settings, sender);
        } catch (SFSCreateRoomException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm getting this error when executing the above code as extension. Any idea is appreciated. I'm not too familiar with java. Thank you

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: *** Null ***
Description: Error while handling client request in extension: { Ext: QyServerExtension, Type: JAVA, Lev: ZONE, { Zone: Qy }, {} }
Extension Cmd: invite
+--- --- ---+
Stack Trace:
+--- --- ---+
com.smartfoxserver.v2.api.SFSGameApi.populateInvitations(SFSGameApi.java:374)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.api.SFSGameApi.createGame(SFSGameApi.java:153)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.api.SFSGameApi.createGame(SFSGameApi.java:83)
qy.server.GameInvitation.handleClientRequest(GameInvitation.java:56)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.extensions.SFSExtension.handleClientRequest(SFSExtension.java:208)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.controllers.v290.ExtensionReqController.processRequest(ExtensionReqController.java:174)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.controllers.v290.ExtensionReqController$1.run(ExtensionReqController.java:68)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My guess is that is has something to do with the invitations, I traced the "invitee" and it's user, also traced other vars and worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
settings.setMinPlayersToStartGame(2);
```

to

```
settings.setMinPlayersToStartGame(1);
```

and it works fine. Still seems strange. I guess. Hope it helps somebody.